# Magento 2: How to secure AJAX request from hacking?

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, security

**How to secure jQuery AJAX request on Client & Server side?**

So there will be minimum risk of hack.

On server side we can use https

Comment: Exactly like any other request: The rule is *"do not trust user data"*. There is nothing special about AJAX requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, we should consider:

#### On the server side:

- Check `isAjax` - `isXmlHttpRequest` on your controller. This prevents the Ajax controller from accessing directly from Browser.
- We can add more logic to validate the data. For example, validate the Json data, check logged customer.

See here : `vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Ajax/Login.php`

#### On the client side:

- We can use `lib/web/mage/storage.js` for performing asynchronous GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
- The data should be JSON string, for example: `JSON.stringify({payment: payment})`

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-information.js*

```
return storage.post(
            serviceUrl, JSON.stringify(payload)
        ).fail(
            function (response) {
                errorProcessor.process(response, messageContainer);
            }
        ).always(
            function () {
                fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
            }
        );
```

We can read more here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AJAX_Security_Cheat_Sheet